# What laws apply to selling / buying bitcoins for USD in California?

Tags: legal, buy-bitcoins, sell-bitcoins

Please help me identify any laws that would be potential blockers to selling and buying bitcoins in person.

Comment: As a commercial, for-profit service, or, for instance, trading them to and from just friends, relatives, coworkers, etc on an infrequent basis?  (There's a difference, so that's why I ask.}

Comment: Assume a for-profit service.

Comment: Hey, are you still there?

Comment: I am, but I don't know the answer.  I am not a lawyer and if this is a for-profit service I'ld recommend you get legal advice.  California is not a state that is necessarily friendly to money transmitters (see https://www.facecash.com/legal/ca.html for an example) but whether buying and selling Bitcoins makes you a money transmitter requiring licensing is not something I can answer.

Comment: I think California should be the same as anywhere else. See this: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/337/what-are-the-legal-processes-that-someone-would-have-to-go-through-in-order-to-g?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

I am not a lawyer but I think this [Bitcoin Magazine Article](http://bitcoinmagazine.net/a-recap-of-mega-corporate-and-government-attention-on-bitcoin-this-past-year/) should be informative. As far as case-law goes I would check out the [bitcoinica bankruptcy suit](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2012/08/bitcoinica-users-sue-for-342qw-in-lost-bitcoins/) as well as the [tradehill bankruptcy suit](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2012/03/lawsuit-illustrates-bitcoins-chargeback-problem/)